# Getting "Class path not found" Error while executing test in Selenium using TestNG

Tags: java, selenium, automation, testng

Below is my code :

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;

public class NewTest {
    public WebDriver driver;
    String driverPath ="F:\\AutomationTesting\\geckodriver-v0.10.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe";
  @Test
  public void main() {

      driver.findElement(By.id("account")).click();

      // Find the element that's ID attribute is 'log' (Username)

      // Enter Username on the element found by above desc.

      driver.findElement(By.id("log")).sendKeys("testuser_1");

      // Find the element that's ID attribute is 'pwd' (Password)

      // Enter Password on the element found by the above desc.

      driver.findElement(By.id("pwd")).sendKeys("Test@123");

      // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element

      driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();

      // Print a Log In message to the screen

      System.out.println(" Login Successfully, now it is the time to Log Off buddy.");

      // Find the element that's ID attribute is 'account_logout' (Log Out)

      driver.findElement(By.id("account_logout"));

  }
  @BeforeMethod
  public void beforeMethod() {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",driverPath);
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      //Put a Implicit wait, this means that any search for elements on the page could take the time the implicit wait is set for before throwing exception

      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

      //Launch the Online Store Website

      driver.get("http://www.onlinestore.toolsqa.wpengine.com");

  }

  @AfterMethod
  public void afterMethod() {
      driver.quit();
  }

}
```

When I try to run my Testsuite using TestNG. I'm getting an Exception like `Class path not found`. I have done cleaning the project, Reinstalled the TestNG. but no luck.

I'm using `Selenium webdriver 3.0`, `Gecko driver` ,`TestNG`.
How do I solve this problem ?

Comment: Cannot find class in classpath: Error

Comment: Please, print whole stacktrace of the error

Comment: How do you executing the test ?

Comment: please add the error log u r getting

Comment: Cannot find class in classpath: NewTest
 at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:81)
 at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:73)
 at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:59)

Comment: at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:582)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)

Comment: at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)

Comment: @NidhunKrishna I didn't find any error as such in your code other than the code formatting errors but you have definitely misguided the SO volunteers by specifying a fake url. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one testing.xml file to execute you all test as a suit

Just add one `testing.xml` file in project root and paste below content in it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="FirstTestSuit">
      <test name="FunctionlTest">
         <classes>      
                      <class name="package.subpackage.TestClassName1"/>                             
                      <class name="package.subpackage.TestClassName2"/> 
         </classes> 
  </test>
</suite>
```

After Saving changes. Right click on project > Run AS > TestNG Suit

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you try to run to run your `testng.xml` as `TestNG suite` and your `classpath` is incorrectly described under `<class>` tag

say you have following class tag in your `testng.xml`:

```
<classes>
  <class name="packageName.yourClassName"/>

</classes>
```

you need to specify correct path which includes package name for your included class.